# StackExchange.Redis Timeout Exception

Tags: redis, stackexchange.redis, node-redis, timeoutexception

I am getting the below error:

Timeout performing EVAL, inst: 2, mgr: Inactive, err: never, queue: 8, qu: 0, qs: 8, qc: 0, wr: 0, wq: 0, in: 3138, ar: 0, clientName: dummy, serverEndpoint: Unspecified/dummy.redis.cache.windows.net:6380, keyHashSlot: 6992, IOCP: (Busy=0,Free=1000,Min=300,Max=1000), WORKER: (Busy=7,Free=32760,Min=300,Max=32767) (Please take a look at this article for some common client-side issues that can cause timeouts: http://stackexchange.github.io/StackExchange.Redis/Timeouts)

Here in the  IOCP: (Busy=0,Free=1000,Min=300,Max=1000) where we can see Busy < Min
and WORKER: (Busy=7,Free=32760,Min=300,Max=32767) , Busy < Min. Even then I am facing the issue.

I gave the ThreadPool.SetMinThreads(300, 300) and set the connectionTimeoutInMilliseconds = 15000 ,         operationTimeoutInMilliseconds = 1000   and retryTimeoutInMilliseconds = 3000

Though I gave the above values, I am facing this issue and was unable to dig the root cause of it.I went through the blogs and doc files related to the same issue but no help.

Can anyone please help me here?